# Montar array de pergunta e respostas

Tags: php, array, foreach

Como faço para montar esse array, poucas vezes fiz `foreach` de `unserialize`, com isso estou com muita dificuldade em fazer essa montagem.

Modelo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### PHP

```
<?php
// $campoBD é a simulação do valor vindo do mysql pela variável $row['prova'];

$campoBD = 'a:2:{i:0;a:7:{i:0;s:27:"<p>Questão 2 de teste:</p>";i:1;s:27:"<p>Questão 3 de teste:</p>";i:2;s:34:"<p>Primeira pergunta de teste:</p>";i:3;s:27:"<p>Questão 4 de teste:</p>";i:4;s:27:"<p>Questão 1 de teste:</p>";i:5;s:16:"<p>TESTE 51?</p>";i:6;s:16:"<p>teste 50?</p>";}i:1;a:7:{i:0;a:4:{i:0;s:18:"a) resposta 1 - Q2";i:1;s:18:"b) resposta 2 - Q2";i:2;s:18:"c) resposta 3 - Q2";i:3;s:18:"d) resposta 4 - Q2";}i:1;a:4:{i:0;s:18:"a) resposta 1 - Q3";i:1;s:18:"b) resposta 2 - Q3";i:2;s:18:"c) resposta 3 - Q3";i:3;s:18:"d) resposta 4 - Q3";}i:2;a:4:{i:0;s:20:"a) Resposta errada 1";i:1;s:21:"b) Resposta errada 2";i:2;s:18:"c) Resposta certa";i:3;s:21:"d) Resposta errada 3";}i:3;a:4:{i:0;s:18:"a) Muito obrigado!";i:1;s:11:"b) Socorro!";i:2;s:37:"c) “Grande nau, grande tormenta”.";i:3;s:39:"d) “A distância alimenta o sonho”.";}i:4;a:4:{i:0;s:18:"a) resposta 1 - Q1";i:1;s:18:"b) resposta 2 - Q1";i:2;s:18:"c) resposta 3 - Q1";i:3;s:18:"d) resposta 4 - Q1";}i:5;a:3:{i:0;s:4:"a) f";i:1;s:4:"b) r";i:2;s:4:"c) r";}i:6;a:3:{i:0;s:13:"a) sdjfjdfsjd";i:1;s:13:"a) sdjfjdfsjd";i:2;s:14:"sdjfsoijdfisoj";}}}'; 

$prova = unserialize($campoBD);

foreach($prova[0] as $rowPergunta) {
  echo $rowPergunta;

  $i = 0;
  foreach($prova[1] as $rowRespostas) {
    echo $rowRespostas[$i] . "<br>";

    $i++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenho minhas dúvidas se serializar as respostas dentro do registro da pergunta é a melhor solução. Até salvar como JSON nesse caso seria bem mais simples dado que você precisa apenas salvar dados estruturados e não objetos da linguagem. CSV também resolveria o problema bem.

Mas partindo do ponto após a deserialização, em que você possui um *array* de perguntas e um *array* com as respostas de cada pergunta, basta fazer:

```php
foreach($prova[0] as $i => $rowPergunta) {
  echo $rowPergunta . "<br>";

  foreach($prova[1][$i] as $rowRespostas) {
    echo $rowRespostas[$i] . "<br>";
  }
}
```

Mas isso não é uma solução legível, pois `$prova[0]` e `$prova[1]` são valores avulsos no código que não expressão sua função dentro dele. O melhor seria definir um código mais semântico:

```php
list($perguntas, $respostas) = $prova;

foreach ($perguntas as $id => $pergunta) {
  echo $pergunta . '<br>';

  foreach ($respostas[$id] as $resposta) {
    echo $resposta . '<br>';
  }
}
```

Ou ainda, reduzindo o segundo laço a um `join`:

```php
list($perguntas, $respostas) = $prova;

foreach ($perguntas as $id => $pergunta) {
  echo $pergunta . '<br>';
  echo join('<br>', $respostas[$id]) . '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Não tenho a sua base, com isto, não consigo simular sua consulta. Mas vou te ajudar a criar o `array()` e como acessar este `array` depois com `foreach()`, e então você adapta a sua necessidade ok?

Segue exemplo:

```
<?
//Criando array de Perguntas
$perguntas[] = "Primeira Pergunta de Teste";
$perguntas[] = "Questão 1 de Teste";
$perguntas[] = "Questão 2 de Teste";
$perguntas[] = "Questão 3 de Teste";
$perguntas[] = "Questão 4 de Teste";

//Criando Array de Respostas
$respostas[] = array(
        "idPergunta" => "0",
        "a" => "resposta errada 1",
        "b" => "resposta errada 2",
        "c" => "Resposta Certa",
        "d" => "resposta errada 3"      
);

$respostas[] = array(
        "idPergunta" => "1",
        "a" => "resposta 1 - Q1",
        "b" => "resposta 2 - Q1",
        "c" => "Resposta 3 - Q1",
        "d" => "resposta 4 - Q1"        
);

$respostas[] = array(
        "idPergunta" => "2",
        "a" => "resposta 1 - Q2",
        "b" => "resposta 2 - Q2",
        "c" => "Resposta 3 - Q2",
        "d" => "resposta 4 - Q2"        
);

$respostas[] = array(
        "idPergunta" => "3",
        "a" => "resposta 1 - Q3",
        "b" => "resposta 2 - Q3",
        "c" => "Resposta 3 - Q3",
        "d" => "resposta 4 - Q3"    
);

//acessando via foreach
foreach($perguntas as $p => $kp){

    echo '<br><br>Perguntas: ' . $kp . '<br>';

    foreach($respostas as $r){
        if($r['idPergunta'] == $p){ //aqui comparo o índice da pergunta com a da Resposta
            echo '<pre>';
            var_dump($r);
        }
    }

}
```

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Olá Leonardo, muito obrigado por me ajudar. Atualizei minha pergunta, com o valor da tabela vinda do mysql. Parece ser um pouco diferente do seu modelo, pois tudo esta dentro de um array único. De uma olhada por gentileza. Obrigado.

Comment: entendo, mas mesmo com o retorno na pergunta é complicado simular aqui. 
tenta interpretar o que eu te passei. Não é difícil trabalhar a estrutura. Eu infelizmente, não consigo simular com os dados que passou. Me desculpe

Comment: Leandro, por favor, copie esse código http://ideone.com/kcW0qk e cole aqui http://phptester.net, vai dar para testar. Só não precisa se atentar ao `preg_replace_callback`, precisei colocar para que seja interpretado meu serialize.

Comment: Bom dia Leandro, deu uma olhada no link acima?

Comment: Simplifiquei meu código original, se poder dar uma olhada. Obrigado.